# Why is my paste made out of red bell pepper tastes a little astringent?

Tags: bell-peppers

The paste was bought from store and I used it a while ago (as earliest February of this year) and then sealed and placed it in the fridge. I have already forgot its taste when I first tasted it. The color of the paste is dark red.

The best-before date without opening the container is in October of 2019.

The ingredients of the paste are: 98% bell pepper, salt, citric acid.

I am not sure if it has gone bad because it smells completely fine.